# Know If a String contains the same sequence in Java

Tags: java, string

OK first at all I want to know how many times I can find the world for example "lazy"

```
String string1= "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
String string2= "The lazy brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
```

I know using the Java String.contains will work the two Strings, but how can I know if in the first String it contains 1 "lazy" word and in the second String 2 "lazy" words, because contains it's a boolean method, so in this case that is not what I need.

I want to know how to do this without the use of Regex, because I'm learning how to create a Regex engine.

Comment: *"I can find the world"*?

Comment: You can use Regular Expressions for this kind of task

Comment: well, your edit just completely changed the game here. you've got 2 other answers though. And they both work fine.

Answer (score 4):

This would do things in one pass using a really simple regex. Of course you can abstract it and make it neat and  tidy, as well.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("lazy");
int occurences;
Matcher m = p.matcher(string1); //etc
while(m.find())
    occurences++;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many possible solutions, but one way would be to do a linear search and count the number of times you see it. The code would look something like this.

```
int countOccurences(String haystack, String needle) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < haystack.length() - needle.length(); i++) 
       if (haystack.substring(i, i + needle.length()).equals(needle)) count++;

    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more noobie friendly approach to this:

```
public class Yolo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String string1= "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
        String string2= "The lazy brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
        String sx1[] = string1.split("\\ ");
        String sx2[] = string2.split("\\ ");
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < sx1.length; i++) {
            if (sx1[i].equalsIgnoreCase("lazy")) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < sx2.length; i++) {
            if (sx2[i].equalsIgnoreCase("lazy")) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Num occurances of lazy = "+count);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Citation from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression):

> A regular expression processor translates a regular expression into a
>   nondeterministic finite automaton (NFA), which is then made
>   deterministic and run on the target text string to recognize
>   substrings that match the regular expression.

If you are really trying to make a regular expression engine, you should learn about state machines, grammars and compilers in general. It is pretty tough, so if you want to start just by searching for substrings, it might be better to do just so.

Very roughly, if you construct a state machine to search for a substring, e.g. for the word "lazy" particulary, it would look something like this:

- the state machine will have 5 states:

  - "not found"
  - "found L"
  - "found LA"
  - "found LAZ"
  - "found LAZY"
- after reading a character, move to the appropriate state

  - e.g. if you are in "not found" and you read **L**, go to "found L" state
  - e.g. if you are in "found LAZ" and you read **Y**, go to "found LAZY" state
  - e.g. if you are in "found LAZ" and you read **$**, go to "not found" state
- if you are in "found LAZY" state, increment the counter and go back to the "not found" state

The advantage and main point of doing this by state automaton and not differently is that you have to walk through the string just once to perform the search.